# sorting and printing multiple lines in a prompted file

Tags: python, list, sorting, user-input

Here is my existing code:

```
filename = input("Enter file name (with extension) to read: ")
if filename == 'x':
    exit()
else:
    c = open(filename, "r")
    print("\nThe file,", filename, "opened successfully!")
    print("The file", filename)
    print(c.readlines())
    c.close()
```

My output is the file I input, which is great! But my problem is that I just need to figure out how to print the list in sorted order. Since the list is generated by the user input, I've not had experience with sorting functions, would I sort the c.readlines directly?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Sorting and printing are covered quite well in available materials.

Comment: I apologize, I feel like that's exactly what I did with my question- I had the entire code written outside of not understanding how to sort a prompted input. I have 4 books I've read, tutorials, and other information and still was unsure on how to execute this- so I came here for help. What am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming is all about decomposition, breaking large problems into smaller pieces. There are several distinct tasks in your program: prompt the user for a file name, open that file, sort the lines, and print them. You've already got a handle on the first two, so cast those out of your mind now and focus on the last two. Whether a file was hardcoded and inputted by the user makes no difference once you've got it open.

To sort a list you have to primary options: call `l.sort()` to sort it in place, or call `sorted(l)` to return a sorted copy without modifying the original. Let's use the second one and loop over the result of `sorted()`:

```
for line in sorted(c.readlines()):
    print(line)
```

The call to `readlines()` is optional. You can also loop over the file directly, which is shorthand for looping over the lines.

```
for line in sorted(c):
    print(line)
```

(I prefer to call `readlines()` explicitly, myself. It's a stylistic choice; either way is acceptable.)

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you John. I had a code in the past that was sorted with the sorted function but it wasn't a user input file, so I was really confused as how that should work. This is so helpful!